# report generation zap-full-scan

Tags: gitlab-ci, gitlab-ci-runner, owasp

hello I'm trying to do a CI / CD integration of zap on gitlab. To do this, I wrote the following code but after running the report is not generated. What to do please.
the scan is well done but the report is not available

```yaml
test_site:
  stage: test
  image: owasp/zap2docker-stable
  when: always
  script:
    - mkdir -p /zap/wrk/
    - zap-full-scan.py -t https://example.com -r report.html
    - cp /zap/wrk/report.html .

  artifacts:
    when: always
    paths: [report.html]
  allow_failure: false
```

I managed to generate the report by adding to the command || true or the -I option but the objective is to generate the report without adding

Answer (score 0):

I have struggled to get this done for more than 2 days. I started with this approach of using `image: owasp/zap2docker-stable` however then had to go to the vanilla docker commands to execute it.

The reason for that is, if you use -r parameter, zap will attempt to generate the file report.html at location `/zap/wrk/`. In order to make this work, we have to mount a directory to this location `/zap/wrk`.

But when you do so, it is important that the zap container is able to perform the write operations on the mounted directory.

So, below is the working solution.

```
  test_site:
          stage: test
          image: docker:latest
          script:
          # The folder zap-reports created locally will be mounted to owasp/zap2docker docker container,
          # On execution it will generate the reports in this folder. Current user is passed so reports can be generated"
            - mkdir zap-reports
            - cd zap-reports
            - docker pull owasp/zap2docker-stable:latest || echo
            - docker run  --name zap-container --rm -v $(pwd):/zap/wrk -u $(id -u ${USER}):$(id -g ${USER}) owasp/zap2docker-stable zap-baseline.py -t "https://example.com" -r report.html
          artifacts:
            when: always
            paths:
              - zap-reports
          allow_failure: true
```

So the trick in the above code is

1. Mount local directory **zap-reports to /zap/wrk** as in `$(pwd):/zap/wrk`
2. Pass the current user and group on the host machine to the docker container so the process is using the same user / group. This allows writing of reports on the directory mounted from local host. This is done by `-u $(id -u ${USER}):$(id -g ${USER})`

Below is the working code with `image: owasp/zap2docker-stable`

```
 test_site:
  variables:
    GIT_STRATEGY: none
  stage: test
  image:
    name: owasp/zap2docker-stable:latest
  before_script:
    - mkdir -p /zap/wrk
  script:
    - zap-baseline.py -t "https://example.com" -g gen.conf -I -r testreport.html
    - cp /zap/wrk/testreport.html testreport.html
  artifacts:
    when: always
    paths:
      - zap.out
      - testreport.html
```